# $K_{\frac{3}{2}}(z)=?$ where $K_{\nu}$ is the modified Bessel function

Tags: analysis, reference-request, special-functions, bessel-functions

The modified bessel function of the second kind is the function $K_n(z)$ which is one of the solutions to the modified Bessel differential equation.

Using Wolframalpha, we get $$K_{\frac{3}{2}}(z)= \sqrt{\frac{π}{2}} \frac{e^{-z} (1 + 1/z)}{\sqrt{z}} \qquad (*)$$

I'm looking for a reference (book or article) which I can find $(*)$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Most books on special functions will have it.  It happens that this comes from the asymptotic expansion, which truncates at half-integer values.  See Digital Library of Mathematical Functions 10.4.2 & 10.40.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For large values of $z$, the asymptotics are given by
$$\sqrt{\frac{2z}{\pi }}\, e^z\,  K_n(z)=1+\frac{4 n^2-1}{8 z}+\frac{16 n^4-40 n^2+9}{128 z^2}+\frac{64 n^6-560 n^4+1036
   n^2-225}{3072 z^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^4}\right)$$

Now, notice that
$$16 n^4-40 n^2+9=16\left(n-\frac 32\right)\left(n-\frac 12\right)\left(n+\frac 12\right)\left(n+\frac 32\right)$$
$$64 n^6-560 n^4+1036
   n^2-225=64\left(n-\frac 52\right)\left(n-\frac 32\right)\left(n-\frac 12\right)\left(n+\frac 12\right)\left(n+\frac 32\right)\left(n+\frac 52\right)$$ and for the particular case of $n=\frac 32$ the rhs reduces exactly to  $1+\frac 1 z$. In fact, if $n=k+\frac 12$, you have simple and nice forms (as *asymptotics* - no $O(.)$)

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \sqrt{\frac{2z}{\pi }}\, e^z\,  K_{k+\frac 12}(z) \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1+\frac{1}{z} \\
 2 & 1+\frac{3}{z}+\frac{3}{z^2} \\
 3 & 1+\frac{6}{z}+\frac{15}{z^2}+\frac{15}{z^3} \\
 4 & 1+\frac{10}{z}+\frac{45}{z^2}+\frac{105}{z^3}+\frac{105}{z^4} \\
 5 & 1+\frac{15}{z}+\frac{105}{z^2}+\frac{420}{z^3}+\frac{945}{z^4}+\frac{945}{z^5} \\
 6 & 1+\frac{21}{z}+\frac{210}{z^2}+\frac{1260}{z^3}+\frac{4725}{z^4}+\frac{10395}{z^5}+\frac{10395}{z^6}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you C. Leibovici, the formulae is given in p. 444 of: M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, Handbook of mathematical functions: with formulas, graphs, and mathematical tables, Vol. 55, 1964. Courier Corporation.

Comment: Thank you C. Leibovici, the formulae is given in p. 444 of: M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, Handbook of mathematical functions: with formulas, graphs, and mathematical tables, Vol. 55, 1964. Courier Corporation.